# How can I store JSON data using Aurora Serverless Mysql 5.6.10

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I am not sure whether I can use JSON as I think it is only available from MySQL version 5.7 and up, I think I should store them as text type or something. Is this the correct approach, or is there a better way to store json data using MySQL 5.6.10.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 5.6 will EOL before it gets feature parity with 5.7 (a hope created back in 2016 IIRC).

https://lefred.be/content/mysql-5-6-eol-is-february-2021/